# Does the "name" parameter for "HttpHeaders.TryGetValues()" care about case sensitivity?

Tags: c#

According to https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2,

> Field names are case-insensitive.

Does the method [HttpHeaders.TryGetValues()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.trygetvalues.aspx) comply with the protocol? (i.e. does the method knows to not take case-sensitivity of the `name` parameter into account?

Comment: Why don't you write a test to try it out?

Comment: Thought it was good to get an answer on SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As noted on the MSDN page,

> A collection of headers and their values as defined in RFC 2616.

So officially, it's part of the contract.

How's reality?

As per the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs), the dictionaries used to store the headers are case insensitive:

```
new Dictionary<string, HeaderStoreItemInfo>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: @neverendingqs Added. It doesn't really matter much, though - the declared interface is what you are promised. If you care about implementation details, all you need to do is *to try*.

Comment: @TonyCheetham I'm sorry you find my answer offensive.

Answer (score 1):

See @Luaan's answer as well.

Sample code:

```
HttpRequestMessage hrh = new HttpRequestMessage();
HttpHeaders headers = hrh.Headers;
headers.Add( "ALLCAPS", "thevalue" );

IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
bool success = headers.TryGetValues( "allcaps", out headerValues );
Assert.IsTrue( success );

Console.Out.WriteLine( String.Join( ",", headerValues ) );
// thevalue
```